# Rename tibco queue by command line

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems

I been looking in google without success.
I´m connected to tibco machine by console, and I would like to rename a queue name.

```
show queue
```

Give me all the details of the queue. I would like to rename it.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, You can't rename queues.

To achieve the same as "renaming" a queue you'd need to:

1. disconnect consumers from the old queue
2. create the new queue
3. move any pending messages from the old queue to the new one
4. create a bridge from the old q. to the new q.
5. reconnect consumers to the new queue
6. delete bridge and old queue when no longer referenced by any producer.

if you are in your own dev environment, just delete the old queue and create the new one (assume you don't care losing pending messages in that case)